# Jetty POST Request returning error code 411

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

Here is my code to run the POST request

```
// Instantiate HttpClient
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    // Configure HttpClient, for example:
    httpClient.setFollowRedirects(false);

    // Start HttpClient
    httpClient.start();


    ContentResponse response = httpClient.POST("url")
            .agent("Mozilla/5.0")
            .method(HttpMethod.POST)
            .param("do","login")
            .param("url","")
            .param("vb_login_md5password", this.password)
            .param("vb_login_md5password_utf", this.password)
            .param("s", "")
            .param("vb_login_username", this.username)
            .param("vb_login_password", "")
            .send();
    for(HttpField h : response.getHeaders())
        System.out.println(h.getName() + " = " + h.getValue());
```

Here is the output

```
Date = Mon, 14 Dec 2015 08:17:08 GMT
Content-Type = text/html
Transfer-Encoding = chunked
Connection = keep-alive
Set-Cookie = __cfduid=dbb11c371945319b1d5943aad06c1977e1450081028; expires=Tue, 13-Dec-16 08:17:08 GMT; path=/; domain=.sythe.org; HttpOnly
Server = cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY = 2548787ba9dc21b6-EWR
```

I look at the ContentResponse text of the post request by doing

```
response.getContentAsString()
```

However for some reason I keep getting a 411 error which tells me my Content-Length is zero or not specified. Is there a way to set the content length header of the post?

Thanks!

EDIT : Doing this makes no difference in my post request

```
.header(HttpHeader.CONTENT_LENGTH, "0")
```

Comment: could you give version and full class name for HttpClient? There's so many of them out there...

Comment: Hey Jan. Thanks for the response! I'm using Jetty-9 which uses this class as its httpclient "import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient;". I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, if there is anything else you need please lmk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.param("do","login")` you specify a *query param* to be added. For the POST to actually contain a body I'd think you need to set `content()` on the request. Maybe a [`FormContentProvider`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.6.v20151106/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/util/FormContentProvider.html) will work for you?

Comment: +100 if I could. Thanks! Do you mind explaining maybe how you found this via the class I gave you in the documentation? That would help me solve my own problems tremendously. Thanks again

Comment: Well - `Content-Length` implies there `is` content (not headers or parameters) in the first place - so I went for a method providing that. Other HttpClient have setRequestEntity() for instance. And then I checked for implementing classes and stumbled upon that FormContentProvider.

Comment: You know, *technically* you could do +100. Unaccept answer, set bounty, let me answer again, accept that. But as it is, I'm glad my hunch played out for you, so no need for that :-)